# Does self-induced collapse limit the size of a quantum computer?

Tags: experimental-realization, decoherence, noise

This question is related to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4162/104), but I'm specifically interested in self-induced collapse. Suppose that the size of a quantum system alone somehow leads to a projection of the state (a "collapse of the wavefunction"), i.e. the collapse is self-induced by the system, without any interaction with an environment which ultimately has some effect on the knowledge of the observer. This is not standard quantum mechanics, but [answers to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/453410) lead me to think that this is a common assumption. My question is: Would this imply that large quantum computers are impossible? Maybe there are even known limits in some models?

Comment: What are the circumstances under which a subsystem comes to 'realise' that it is part of a larger quantum computing system? An answer to this might be necessary to rule out approaches to overcoming the collapse through error correction, to realise universal QC.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I guess that depends on the collapse model, for the "Penrose interpretation" there seems to be some threshold energy of some form, such that superpositions of vastly different energies are impossible?